# Are electrons points or Kerr naked ring singularities?

Tags: black-holes, electrons, singularities, kerr-newman-metric

I have heard contradictory descriptions of electrons as both points and kerr naked ring singularities, with that said which is it? Are they rings or are they points? Are they somehow both?

Comment: The Compton wavelength of the electron is much larger than its Schwarzschild radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quantum field theory, it's a point particle. But that's before you include gravity.

If you ignore quantum mechanics, but include gravity as well as charge, you might expect a black hole, except that the charge repulsion is stronger than the gravitational attraction. So there is no event horizon, and instead you end up with the spinning-ring naked singularity.

In string theory so far, it's neither of those, it's a string or a brane. The very-short-range gravitational forces are different in string theory, e.g. because of the excited states of the graviton-string, and there's no naked singularity.

In quantum field theory, the magnetic moment of the electron is derived [from the linearity of the Dirac equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#Gyromagnetic_factor_as_a_consequence_of_relativity). But there is a kind of derivation of an electron's magnetic moment, which comes from trying to treat it as a black hole. This is one reason why interest in the "black hole electron" persists.

Apparently [one may hope](http://books.google.com/books?id=ykV8cZxZ80MC&pg=PA832) that a version of this black-hole argument is still valid, even if an electron is actually not a black hole. I have no idea if there is any prospect of this working out within string theory. That would be cool, but not every cool idea gets to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Since electrons are on the edge between Quantum and Relativity it is hard to make some binding statements here, but there are sources that use the Kerr-Newman-metric to describe at least some properties of the electron:

[The Dirac-Kerr-Newman electron](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0507109.pdf) and
 [Kerr Geometry as
    Space-Time Structure of the Dirac Electron](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0577.pdf)

There is also a Wikipedia-article on the subject:

[The black hole electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_electron)

I hope that helps